# How to efficiently calculate matrix operations when the elements are defined as functions?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, numerics

I'm trying to calculate the one-body density matrix of a system of particles as described in [this article](https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.95.043622), given in equations 14 and 15.

Here, is my code but it seems very slow. Is there any efficient way to calculate it in Mathematica?

```
\[Omega]z = 2 \[Pi] 14.3;
hbar = 1.05457*10^-34; (* Planck's constant *)
kb = 1.38065*10^-23; (* Boltzman's constant *)
mCs = 132.9054*1.6605*10^-27; (* mass Cs-Atom *)
lho = Sqrt[hbar/(mCs *\[Omega]z)];
Lmax = 10;
Np = 5;
\[Mu] = 2.3*10^-32;

Energy[n_] := (2 n + 1) *(hbar/2)* \[Omega]z;


f[i_] := 1/(Exp[(Energy[i] - \[Mu])/(kb*T)] + 1);

\[Psi][z_][n_] := 
  N[Exp[-0.5 (z/lho)^2]*
    HermiteH[n, z/lho]*(1/(N[\[Pi]]^(1/4) Sqrt[2^n n! lho]))] ;
\[Psi]bar[z_][n_] := 
  N[Exp[-0.5 (z/lho)^2]*
     HermiteH[n, z/lho]*(1/(N[\[Pi]]^(1/4) Sqrt[2^n n! lho])) /. 
    I -> -I ];

Pjk[z_][j_, k_] := 
  Pjk[z][j, k] = 
   Exp[-z^2]*(HermiteH[j + 1, z]*HermiteH[k, z] - 
      HermiteH[j, z]*HermiteH[k + 1, z])*(1/(
     2*(j - k)*Sqrt[2^(j + k) \[Pi] j! k!]));
Mj[z_, 0] = 0;
Mj[z_, j_] := 
  Mj[z, j] = 
   Mj[z, j - 1] + 
     Exp[-z^2]*HermiteH[j, z]*
      HermiteH[j + 1, z]*(1/(2^(j + 1)*((j + 1)!))) // N;
P[x_, y_][j_, k_] := 
  P[x, y][j, k] = 
   If[j == k, 
    1 - 2*Sign[y - x]*f[j - 1]* (Mj[y, j - 1] - Mj[x, j - 1]), -2*
     Sign[y - x]*
     Sqrt[f[j - 1]*f[k - 1]]*( 
      Pjk[y][j - 1, k - 1] - Pjk[x][j - 1, k - 1])];
pmat[x__, y__] := Array[P[x, y], {Lmax, Lmax}] // N;
(*qmat[x_,y_]:=ConjugateTranspose[Inverse[pmat[x,y]]]*Det[pmat[x,y]];*)


qmat[x_, y_] := 
  N[ConjugateTranspose[LinearSolve[pmat[x, y], IdentityMatrix[Lmax]]]*
    Det[pmat[x, y]]];
allpsi[x_] := 
  allpsi[x] = Table[\[Psi][x][i]*Sqrt[f[i]], {i, 0, Lmax - 1}] // N;
allpsibar[y_] := 
  allpsibar[y] = 
   Table[\[Psi]bar[y][i]*Sqrt[f[i]], {i, 0, Lmax - 1}] // N;
densitymat[x_, y_] := 
  Parallelize[allpsi[x] . qmat[x, y] . allpsibar[y]];
Plot[densitymat[x, 0], {x, 0, 5 lho}, PlotRange -> All]
```

For example, for (Lmax=10, Np=5), it takes around 5s, for(Lmax=20,Np=10), it's around 80s, and for (Lmax=50, Np=10), it's more than 600s. Is there any way to perform these matrix operations more efficiently so that we can push it to higher values of (Lmax,Np)?
Finally, I would like to do a Fast Fourier transform of `densitymat`.